# Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list in execute script

Tags: python, pytest, ui-automation, execute-script

When I run the following:

```py
self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementByXpath('//input[@id='someid']').value='someValue';
```

It gives an error

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message:
javascript error: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: You missed a parenthesis after the semi-colon, and you have to change the single quote to double-quotes (`"string"` instead of `'string'`) in one of the places.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the same kind of quote in two different levels of parsing, and so `'//input[@id='` is interpreted as one string literal, after which `someid` is unexpected.

Change:

```
document.getElementByXpath('//input[@id='someid']')
```

To:

```
document.getElementByXpath('//input[@id=\"someid\"]')
```